# How to get a svg line element total length

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a very simple svg with just one line on it

```
<svg version="1.1" id="animation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" baseProfile="tiny">
    <line id="line-1" style="stroke:#777777;stroke-miterlimit:10;" x1="358" y1="332.5" x2="371.3" y2="364.7"/>
</svg>
```

and I use jquery to get the line and find it length with getTotalLength()

```
var len = $("#line-1").get(0).getTotalLength();
```

but my browser keeps giving this error warning

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).getTotalLength is not a function

Can anyone tell me if line element can use getTotalLength()? If not, how can I get the length of the line.

Thanks.

here's my example: https://jsfiddle.net/chitocheng/1h5eckjh/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `line` doesn't store the length so you need to get it yourself using the distance formula:

```
var line = $("#line-1").get(0);
var len = dist(line.x1.baseVal.value, line.x2.baseVal.value,
               line.y1.baseVal.value, line.y2.baseVal.value);

$("#len").text(len);

function dist(x1, x2, y1, y2){
    return Math.sqrt( (x2-=x1)*x2 + (y2-=y1)*y2 );
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1h5eckjh/3/)

But a `path` does support the `getTotalLength()` function. So if you want to use it you need to use a `<path>` rather then a `<line>`. To setup your `<line>` as a `<path>` you can do:

```
<path id="line-1" style="stroke:#777777;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 358,332.5 L 371.3,364.7"/>
```

[**Fiddle Path Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1h5eckjh/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the `getTotalLength()` tip. Thankfully, it seems that a new way of dealing with path length is [**in the workings**](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/177) :)

Comment: The `dist` function is not equivalent to `getTotalLength`, I just tested and it's off by a mile.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone trying to  know if in 2020 :
JQUERY (3.4.1) >> `$('#lineID').get(0).getTotalLength()`
JS >> `document.getElementById('lineID').getTotalLength()`
works on `<lines/>`
the answer is yes.

Browsers tested :
Firefox 76.0.1
Chromium: 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chrome  83.0.4103.61
Opera 68.0.3618.125

https://jsfiddle.net/mzyd4ura/2/

Comment: For nonambiguous answer do change the `<lines/>` (original post) to `<line>` elements. SVG supports only `<polyline>` and `<polygon>` (and of course `<path>`, too) for multiline elements.